How do futurists understand Revelation 12?
In an answer to another question, user SLM references an interpretive framework of Revelation from Hal Linsey that derives an interpretation of the overall structure of the book from 1:19.


Write the things which thou hast seen, and the things which are, and the things which shall be hereafter; Rev 1:19

What was, what is, what will be. This is the instruction about which to write.
What was is chapter one wherein John describes what he sees.
What is are the letters to the seven churches; that is, letters to the church age in chapters two and three.
What will be is after the church age, since what is, is the church age.
After this [literally after these things] I looked, and, behold, a door was opened in heaven: and the first voice which I heard was as it were of a trumpet talking with me; which said, Come up hither, and I will shew thee things which must be hereafter. Rev 4:1
This is the rapture.
After these things, the church age, the what is, ends at the rapture, the door in heaven open, a voice of the trumpet, calls to come up to heaven, to show what will be hereafter. Revelation now turns to the what will be, which is basically tribulation period. Churches are not mentioned again until the end at Rev. 22:16.

This connects to a futurist reading of Revelation 4-21, which sees the prophecies as things to be fulfilled in the future. I have also heard the same argument (based on Rev.1:19) made by two different dispensationalist pastors, which they used to argue that the prophecies of Rev. 4-21 refer to future events, or even more strongly to argue that they are arranged in chronological order.
I'm wondering how Revelation 12:1-5 fits into this framework, as I've only ever heard it interpreted as referring to the first coming of Christ (which especially makes sense because of the reference to Psalm 2 in Rev.12:5.). Obviously, that's an event which happened prior to the composition of the book, so it doesn't fit with a strictly futuristic reading of Rev.4-21. It also would demonstrate that the visions are not all in chronological order.
So I am wondering whether: 1. There is an alternative, futurist interpretation of Rev.12:1-5 or 2. Futurists do not actually take all of Rev. 4-21 as future and/or do not take all of it as chronological.

I've heard it said that that particular section is parenthetical.


OP:  So I am wondering whether: 1. There is an alternative, futurist interpretation of Rev.12:1-5 or 2. Futurists do not actually take all of Rev. 4-21 as future and/or do not take all of it as chronological.

Hal Lindsey who recently passed graduated from the Dallas Theological Seminary with a Master of Theology in 1962.  One of his teachers (I believe) was Dr. J. Dwight Pentecost who published a book Things To Come in 1958.  They taught the timeline and structure of Revelation as the OP summarized from my previous answer (chronological and future).  So, what about specifically Revelation 12:1-5?
They taught that Revelation 12:1-5 referred to Israel, the woman who produced the child Christ.  It cannot and does not refer to the Christian church, given that the church had been raptured by that time per the ending of Revelation 3 and start of 4 (the come up here as the rapture).
Plus, Revelation 12:13 refers to Satan's (great) wrath on earth as the tribulation from which Christians are protected.  To quote from page 215, "the reason Satan turns against Israel can only be explained by the absence of the church from that scene."
So, to answer the OP, this explains the futurist and chronological view of Revelation as regards that specific verse/chapter.
EDIT TO ADD DETAIL ON THE WOMAN
In the dispensational premillennial view, the woman of Rev 12 refers to Israel.  She brought forth Christ.  Christ brought forth the church.
Per Micah 5 and Rev 12, this is the pattern of birth of the ruler, the rejection, the setting aside, the continuing travail.  In effect, Israel brought forth Christ about 2,000 years ago and is still travailing until recognition of Jesus the Messiah.
As I mentioned in the comments, "from my [chronological] understanding, the pregnancy is of Christ (second coming) and birth are of Israel recognizing its Messiah during the tribulation."

So is the event described in vv.1-5 not the birth of Christ then?

Correct.  The futurist/chronologist would say this refers to Israel, during the tribulation as they begin to recognize the truth.  Additionally, with the phrase "she PAINED to be in birth" cannot refer to Mary in the version of Catholicism "no pain".  The 3 1/2 years refers to tribulation also.  If it was the church, we've been here about 2,000 years.

Under this framework, what is the identity of the child born to the woman?

The child born of the woman is Christ (Psalm 2) according to dispensationalists, among others.  Yes, Christ is born before Chapter 12, but the context is clear enough IMO.

I am a bit confused--does this mean the birth of the child (Christ) is therefore not signifying the event of Christ's birth? Or is the chronology not absolutely consistent?

Christ had already been birthed.  The woman (Israel) birthed Christ.  Christ birthed the church.  The view in Rev 12 is to identify the woman.  It is about Israel in the end times.  It's not about the birth of Christ.  There's no mention of the church, except as it is in heaven (Rev 12:5).

I'm not sure why the location of the church is relevant here. I'm asking a simple question: are the pregnancy (v.2) and birth (v.4-5) taken as past events or some future event distinct from the first coming of Christ?

To try to clarify, from my understanding, the pregnancy is of Christ (second coming) and birth are of Israel recognizing its Messiah during the tribulation.   Sorry for the confusion.

I see. Could you update your answer with that interpretation and then I'll accept?

The book of Revelation can be seen as chronological, with occasional asides providing supplemental information.
(Note that a chronological view does not match the pre-Tribulation "Rapture" story as described in the question.)
The United Church of God for instance publishes this
Infographic: Chapter Outline of the Book of Revelation:




Chapter
Story Flow
Insets*




1
Introduction



2-3

Message to the seven churches


4-5
Prelude-setting



6
First six seals



7
144,000 and the great multitude



8-10
Seventh seal opened: The trumpet plagues



11
The two witnesses



12

The true Church


13

The two beasts


14

The three messages


15-16
The seven last plagues



17-18

The false church


19
The return of Jesus Christ



20
The Millennium



21-22
The new heaven and new earth




Several chapters in the book are insets.
Although most of the book's chapters flow in chronological order,
these chapters describe background events and conditions that are not part of the story flow and may span centuries.

It's also helpful to understand that the Seventh Seal contains the Seven Trumpets, and the Seventh Trumpet contains the Seven Plagues.
See my answer to
How does the 4th trumpet (in Revelation 8:12) happen after the 6th seal (in Revelation 6:12)?
for more details.

It seems like this view may lend itself to criticism regarding the islands/mountains as described in the 6th seal but also the 7th trumpet - have you come across this argument or aware of such a discussion? I personally find it hard to believe that the similarities in expression would be referring to anything other than the same event, but if chronological this would not be so. Any suggestions for further reading on this specifically?

So is 12:1-5 one of the asides? If so, can Revelation truly be considered chronological?

@AlanFuller asks "is 12:1-5 one of the asides?" — All of Chapter 12 is an aside, a summary of the history of Satan's animosity toward God's people and the events leading up to and including the 3½ years of Tribulation.

@JacobMcDougle mentions "islands/mountains as described in the 6th seal but also the 7th trumpet" — Revelation 6:14 (sixth seal) says "every mountain and island was moved out of its place", while Revelation 16:20 (seventh plague bowl) says "every island fled away, and the mountains were not found".  The second event is much more severe than the first.

@JacobMcDougle, it should be noted that the mountains and islands also symbolically represent governments.

@RayButterworth Perhaps a separate question/post is in order - will be working on it and share once it's done.

I suppose I could be called a semi-futurist, but I'm not a dispensationalist.
This is the approach adopted in my own book. John is writing in the first instance to the church of his own time, which is experiencing the beginnings of the Roman persecution. That is what he means by "I share with you the tribulation" (ch1 v9). From at least ch7 v1, I would regard him as looking into the more distant future (ch6 v11 speaks of a second set of martyrs to be suffering later).
But ch11 is continued by ch14, and the intervening chapters are really a flashback explaining why all the persecutions are happening in the first place.
It comes down to the fact that Satan is the Accuser, the one who accuses men of their sins before God. That is the source of his power over them. But this power is destroyed, as far as the saints are concerned, by the work of Christ. ch12 vv10-11 explains that he has been overcome, "thrown down from heaven", by the Atonement which has brought them forgiveness ("the blood of the Lamb") and by the teaching of the gospel of forgiveness ("the word of their testimony"). On that basis, I regard the first nine verses of ch12 as a dramatized version of the doctrine of the Atonement.
Satan then seeks revenge, as described over the next chapter and a half, by finding another way to attack the saints who have been taken out of his grasp. He arranges the great persecution. In effect, "If I cannot accuse the saints before God, then I will accuse them before human authority instead."
